# Compare $(1+i)^t$ and $1+i\cdot t$ for positive $i$ and $t$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $i>0$. Show that

(i) if $0<t<1$ then $(1+i)^t < 1+i \cdot t$, and

(ii) if $t>1$ then $(1+i)^t > 1+ i\cdot t$.

For (ii), if I took the limit of $\frac{(1+i)^t}{(1+i\cdot t)}$ as $t$ approaches infinity and showed that it was $0$, would that be valid?

For (i) I thought about taking derivatives to show that the rate of change of one function is greater than the other over the interval.

I am not sure how to go through with either of these ideas for the problems, or if I am even in the right direction. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Take the function $f(x)=(1+x)^t-1-xt$ with $t> 0$. Note that $f(0)=0$ and for $x>0$, we have
$$
f'(x)=t\left((1+x)^{t-1}-1\right)
$$
which is strictly positive for $t>1$ and strictly negative for $t<1$. By the Mean Value Theorem, you can infer that $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$ whenever $t>1$ and $f(x)<0$ for all $x>0$ whenever $t\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is immediately obvious if you use Bernoulli inequality (which you probably can't), but for (ii) it's better to show using Binomial expansion, so that LHS is 
$$
(1+r)^n = 1+ \binom{n}{1}r + R(n,r)
$$
with the remainder term strictly positive, hence your inequality.